# Windows 7 Power plan not listening

Tags: windows-7, display, sleep, power-management

I'm trying to fix my friends windows 7 computer.
After about 30-45 minutes the computer screen goes black only when not in use.
I have reset the power/sleep setting to default, deleted any custom settings. But the problem persists. The plan says to never shut down hard drive and shut down monitor after 4 hours.
Any ideas ?

PS> I read somewhere to try pressing the numlock key when screen is black to see if light comes on, well all that does is wake the computer and yes the light comes on, and I am monitoring the internal temp of the PC and its running at a constant 30 degrees.

Comment: if it i hibernating/suspending, I always have to explicitly disable hibernation even though the system is set to never hibernate. in an elevated command prompt, run `powercfg -h off`. if you are just worried about monitor sleep, make sure the monitor doesn't implement its own power save timer. many do.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't think it's hibernating because it comes on instantly. I'll check monitor and try the command prompt route though.

Answer (score -1):

click start button 
open control panel
click small icons
click power option

change plan settings 
select never option 
save changes ok

change plan settings 
select never option 
save changes

okk

Comment: You'll need to reformat this and provide slightly more guidance on what is being done and why for it to be a suitable answer.  It'll get down voted and likely deleted unless you improve it.